# AWS CodeDeploy Application install step not working (CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to deploy using CodeDeploy.

And I'm followed all of the tutorial from aws docs.

But that give a below log.

Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

`2018-06-23 06:42:38 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(26957)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Missing credentials - please check if this instance was started with an IAM instance profile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your issue is that the EC2 instance does not have an IAM instance profile associated with it. In order for the CodeDeploy agent to communicate with CodeDeploy, it needs to get IAM credentials. [Here's an overview and more details on how it needs to be set up.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/auth-and-access-control.html)

In a nutshell, your instance needs an IAM instance profile that has the appropriate permissions to talk with CodeDeploy and download from S3. If you're using CodeDeploy on-premise instances, the setup is different. See [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/instances-on-premises.html).